# jquery post request catching failed request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

In the front-end JS, I am sending a request to the backend:

```
  $.post("/test", data, () => {
    console.log("received");
  })
    .done(() => {
      console.log("request finished");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
```

In the backend, I am purposely causing the request to fail:

```
app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.status(400).send("Error message");
})
```

Apparently, the 400 error was not caught by the `.fail` block. I later tried using try catch block:

```
  try {
    await $.post("/test", data, () => {
      console.log("received");
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Still, the error slipped. I ran out of ideas now. How should I catch the error returned by the jquery post request then?

Comment: Check the response in browser devtools. Is it actually returning the 400 HTTP status code to the client side?

Comment: You could, also, try 404 instead of 400.

Comment: `POST http://localhost:2000/test 400 (Bad Request)` this is the error that gives me